# jQuery wrap around first depth li's

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Im trying to get some jQuery code working for a menu..
I need to wrap a `<ul>` around my first-depth `<li>`'s

My HTML Syntax look like that..

```
<ul>
  <li id="" class="menu-item">
     <a class="" href="#">test1</a>

    <div class="sub">
         <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li id="" class="menu-item">
                  <a class="" href="#">test2</a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                      <li id="" class="menu-item"><a class="" href="">test</a></li>
                      <li id="" class="menu-item"><a class="" href="">test</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>   
              <li id="" class="menu-item">
                  <a class="" href="#">test3</a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                      <li id="" class="menu-item"><a class="" href="">test</a></li>
                      <li id="" class="menu-item"><a class="" href="">test</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>    
          </ul>
     </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is how it should look after inserting the `<ul>` tags

```
 <ul>
      <li id="" class="menu-item">
         <a class="" href="#">test1</a>

        <div class="sub">
             <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <ul class="drop_menu">
                  <li id="" class="menu-item">
                      <a class="" href="#">test2</a>
                      <ul class="sub-menu">
                          <li id="" class="menu-item"><a class="" href="">test</a></li>
                          <li id="" class="menu-item"><a class="" href="">test</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li> 
                  </ul>  
                  <ul class="drop_menu">
                  <li id="" class="menu-item">
                      <a class="" href="#">test3</a>
                      <ul class="sub-menu">
                          <li id="" class="menu-item"><a class="" href="">test</a></li>
                          <li id="" class="menu-item"><a class="" href="">test</a></li>
                      </ul>
                   </li>
                   </ul>    
              </ul>
         </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

The `<ul class="drop_menu">` should only be wrapped around the first-level li's... Didn't find any solution for that until now.. Hope anyone has an idea..

Cheers!

Comment: Your result isn't valid HTML, a `<ul>` can't be the child of a `<ul>`, it needs to be within a `<li>`, is this the desired result?

Comment: Do you have a good method for grabbing the "parent" ul? i.e. any way to definitivly only select that ul element and not any children underneath? If so, you can use [ulselect] > li (the `>` will select the direct child and not traverse all children.

Comment: Hi.. Best would be deleting the first "ul class=sub menu", which is around the whole list. Then 2 new ul's around the first-level-li's It's annoying but I can't edit the html structure because it's all wrapped up dynamically..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to select all `li`s *directly* inside the `<div>`'s `<ul>`:

```
$('ul > li.menu-item > div.sub > ul.sub-menu > li.menu-item')
```

The [`a > b` child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) will select all `b` elements that are a direct child of an `a`.

---

**EDIT**: You're also looking for the [`.unwrap()` method](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/).

Comment: No.. I only want to select the first level list elements.. Not all the li-elements..

Answer (score 1):

if wrapping around 1st level li's then:

$('ul.drop_menu > li').each(function(){
//do something in each li using this
});

Answer (score 0):

The following jQuery should do the trick...

```
$('div.sub > ul.sub-menu > li.menu-item').wrap('<ul class="drop_menu"></ul>');
```